# resources must be listed in the web accessible resources manifest key in order to loaded by the pages outside the extension

Tags: tailwind-css, developer-tools

I have creating a  react project using vite and for styling  i have install the tailwindcss and do all it's procedure but when i'm applying the css . I can't see on the webpage but the css property is visible on opening the dev tools.

I'm getting an error that's:
Denying load of chrome-extension://iadokddofjgcgjpjlfhngclhpmaelnli/src/assets/styles.css. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

I'm trying to apply tailwind css  on a heading element and expecting that the css is will apply on that element but no thing will happen with that element.

Comment: That error message comes from your CareerFlow extension not loading correctly. It is not related to the non-working tailwind styles. Could you post your code? Specifically your tailwind config file, and the file you're trying to style?

Comment: my tailwind config :


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
this is my component where im using the css :  
 function App() {
  

  return (
    <>
     <h1 className='border-2 border-black'>Hello </h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

Comment: Edit your question, don't add it as a comment here :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.